# Why @screen-xs-min and anything haven't run?

Tags: bootstrap-4, responsive

This is result:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVOZc.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mzSf.png
```

Here my code:

```
https://codepen.io/hienphanVN/pen/gOagRXK
```

The background-color don't change despite of I used to @screen-xs-min. Have no property inside @media (min-width: @screen-xs-min;) run. I don't know why. Thanks for your help.
(bootstrap 4.1 connected anything I checked. Which component I loss ?)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please remember to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Such as what you've tried so far, what failed, what research you did.

Comment: try to add `!important` in CSS property

Comment: thanks, I tried, but nothing happen, What should I do on next step ?

Comment: you need to provide code, for next process

Comment: Thanks for your sugguest, but I don't know which way suitable. Could you give me a hint or keyword? For Google, I very thankful for you .

Comment: you can provide us your code that shows your problem clearly, you can use codepen.io for sharing your code to us

Comment: Ok, Just a moment

Comment: Hi Nisharg Shah, I updated my question, please check again, thanks for all